# Abstract Python

Tags: python

I need to a have a abstract class that maintains a grade and should have an operation `get_grade()` that returns a value on a 4.0 scale and must be abstract. Here what I have so far:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Assessment:

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def get_grade(self)
        return
```

What am I doing wrong in this and how do I return a value on a 4.0 scale?

Comment: First, why have you tagged this `python-2.7` and `python-3.x`. Which is it? And are you actually using wxpython or PIL in any way relevant to the problem?

Comment: Anyway, the first thing you're doing wrong is missing the colon on your `def` statement, which means you'll get a `SyntaxError`. The second thing you're doing wrong is either specifying the metaclass incorrectly (if you're using 3.x), or trying to use a classic class as an ABC (if 2.x).

Comment: Once you fix those problems, you're not doing _anything_ wrong. It all works as expected. Which is to say, it does nothing useful unless you also define at least one concrete subclass that implements `get_grade`.

Comment: @abarnert im using python idk why I tag all of those... but how do I return a value on a 4.0 scale? also the subclass that I have that implements get_grade is my Essay subclass here what I have                                                                                                                                    class Essay(Assessment)                                                        def get_grade(self)                 now did I implement that right?

Comment: OK, _which_ Python are you using? 2.7? 3.3? 1.5? Meanwhile, what do you mean "how do I return on a 4.0 scale?" How do you return _what_ on a 4.0 scale? A function that just does `return 3.0` is returning on a 4.0 scale.

Comment: Sorry, you're not actually using a classic class as an ABC with 2.x, because of course ABCMeta will evaluate the definition as an ABCMeta instance, not a ClassType, so it ends up a new-style class anyway.

Comment: this is a Gradebook assignment once I get the averages of the essay and teamproject subclass I need to return it on a 4.0 scale @abarnert

Comment: I'm assuming you have some other code you haven't described that takes a bunch of `Assessment` objects, gets their grades, and averages them. If the grades are all on a 4.0 scale, the average is also already on a 4.0 scale, so there's nothing tricky to do there either.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not very helpful to ask "What am I doing wrong" without explaining what makes you think it's wrong.

However, there are two problems with your code.

First, you're going to get a `SyntaxError` on this line:

```
def get_grade(self)
```

`def` statements, like all block-introducing statements, need a colon, and you don't have one.

Next, when you fix that, your code will compile, but it won't work properly if you're using 3.x. It's not clear whether you're using Python 2.x or 3.x, but if it's 3.x, you're not specifying a metaclass, you're just creating a class variable named `__metaclass__` that does nothing. (Also, if you're using 2.x, your class is defined as a classic class, but becomes a new-style class when its body is evaluated by the metaclass, which may be confusing.)

So, the correct 2.x version of your code is:

```
class Assessment(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod
    def get_grade(self):
        return
```

And the correct 3.x version is:

```
class Assessment(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_grade(self):
        return
```

Once you fix that, your code works. It creates an abstract class with an abstract method, which you can easily test:

```
>>> a = Assessment()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Assessment with abstract methods get_grade
>>> class Concrete(Assessment): pass
>>> b = Concrete()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods get_grade
>>> class Concrete2(Assessment):
...     def get_grade(self): pass
>>> c = Concrete2()
>>> class External(object):
...     def get_grade(self): pass
>>> Assessment.register(External)
>>> d = External()
```

Of course this is just the start of your assignment. You obviously need to create at least one concrete subclass of `Assessment` (or a class that you call `Assessment.register` on) that does something useful in `get_grade`.

---

Here's an example subclass that "returns a value on a 4.0 scale". I have no idea if it's anything like what you're supposed to do for your assignment, because all you've given us is that one phrase, but…

```
class PopQuiz(Assessment):
    def __init__(self, score_out_of_100):
        self.score_out_of_100 = score_out_of_100
    def get_grade(self):
        score_out_of_4_0 = self.score_out_of_100 / 25.0
        return score_out_of_4_0
```

Comment: the subclass that I have is called Essay it consist of a single grade (a number on the 4.0 scale) it implement get_grade operation here what I have for that                                                                class Essay(assessment):

def get_grade(self)
I don't know if I should add more to this or leave it like this @abarnet

Comment: Then it sounds like you just need to return that number: `def get_grade(self): return self.a`.

Comment: so for the class Essay would I just leave it like this @abarnet

Comment: Leave what like what? If `Essay` has an attribute `a` that's a grade on a 4.0 scale, and you want to add a `get_grade` method that returns a grade on a 4.0 scale, just add the `def` statement from my last comment, and you're done.

Comment: what I have for ESSAY would I be ok with how I had it? and were would I add the def that your talking bout @abarnert

Comment: You haven't shown us what you have to `Essay`, so it's hard to say if it's right, or point out where to change it. Also, without knowing exactly what your assignment is, it's hard to guess whether you're doing it right. And meanwhile, this site just doesn't work for tutoring someone through a long stream of followup questions. If you can't fit your followup questions to the SO format (either posting a new question, or editing this one), it's going to be very hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: if I submit what the assignment is and what I have done so far would you be able to help me then?

Comment: do you have a email that I can reach you at?